# MVC Partial View to Create/List Items and Redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-mvc-partialview

What I'm trying to achieve is essentially have a view that at the top displays a form to enter new post, then below the form it will display a list of posts that already exist. Also I'm trying to make this view somewhat generic so that it can show different type of posts.

To be clear, by post I mean something like a facebook status post and not a Http-Post.

Imagine you have home page that displays all the posts, and then you have a profile page that displays only the posts connected to that profile.

So I have my _Posts partial view which looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Post>

@Html.Partial("_CreatePost", new Post())

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="Post">
        <h5>@item.Title</h5>
        <p>@DateTime.Now.Subtract(item.Date).ToString("mm") minutes ago</p>
        <p>@item.Content</p>
    </div>
}
```

The code for the partial view is:

```
@model MVC_Test_CRUD.Models.Post

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Post")) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Post</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
        </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And I successfully display a list of posts and I'm able to create new posts as well.

I also have a standard Create Action in my controller, which results in

```
return RedirectToAction("Index")
```

if the creation was successful. So my question is how can I send additional parameter to the controller about where to redirect (home/index or profile/index or somewhere else) depending on where

```
@Html.Partial("_CreatePost", new Post())
```

was inserted.

Comment: did you try to add a hidden value of PostType in your ViewModel, and use it on your controller to make decision where to redirect ?

Comment: i did not think of that, that will work for sure

Comment: do you want me to post that as answer, with more details?

Comment: I think I'll be able to make it work using hidden value. Anyway I was trying to find what would the best practice be in a scenario like this.